# unitval.replace statements overwriting other part of code?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert units within an excel file. The code below was working until I added the `unitval.replace` statements, after which the unit conversion doesn't occur. These are to replace , to . in the data and " " to no space. Is it possible to write something like this and still get the unit conversion code below it to work? Thanks!

```
def unitConversion(ssheet,scollist,units,c):
    if (units != None):
        unitval = str(ssheet.cell_value(units,c))
        factor = 1
    if "," in unitval:
        unitval = unitval.replace(",",".")
    if " " in unitval:
        unitval = unitval.replace(" ", "")
        try:
            factor = REF.conversions[unitval]
            for i in range(0,len(scollist),1):
                try:
                    scollist[i] = float(scollist[i]) * factor
                except:
                    if (scollist[i] == ""):
                        scollist[i] = ""
                    elif ((scollist[i][0] == "<") or (scollist[i][0] == ">")):
                        temp = float(scollist[i][1:])
                        scollist[i] = "-" + str(temp/1000)
```

Comment: What is `ssheet`? Which of the several available Python Excel libraries are you using? What does the spreadsheet contain? Please read [ask].

Comment: Could it simply be that the first `try` isn't supposed to be under the `if " " in unitval:`?  A whole bunch of your code now only runs if there's a space in `unitval`.

Comment: ...also, there's no reason I can see for the 2nd and 3rd `if`s.  Just do the replacement unconditionally.  Otherwise, you're just doing extra walks over `unitval` for no real reason. (assuming the `try` is in the wrong place) - The string won't be copied if no replacement is done.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I believe you are correct, I have moved the try and it is working now. Thanks for spotting the easy fix!  And good advice regarding the replacement